# PhalconPHP: how to autoload

Tags: php, autoload, phalcon

I've found this page on autoloading with PhalconPHP:  http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/loader.html

I understand what I need to do to set up the loader.  However, my question is, now that I have a $loader variable...  what do I do with it?  Is there something I need to attach it to?  My guess was to add it to the $di, but the $di doesn't seem to have a 'loader' key.

```
// Creates the autoloader
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

//Register some namespaces
$loader->registerNamespaces(
    array(
       "Example\Base"    => "vendor/example/base/",
       "Example\Adapter" => "vendor/example/adapter/",
       "Example"         => "vendor/example/",
    )
);

// register autoloader
$loader->register();

// ***  What goes here?
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could have only ``"Example"         => "vendor/example/"`` btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Creates the autoloader
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

//Register some namespaces
$loader->registerNamespaces(
    array(
       "Example\Base"    => "vendor/example/base/",
       "Example\Adapter" => "vendor/example/adapter/",
       "Example"         => "vendor/example/",
    )
);

// register autoloader
$loader->register();

$var = new Example\Base();
```

Specified namespaces and classes will be loaded automaticly when you want to use them.

Answer (score 4):

Also don't forget, if you are using composer it's always easier (and often better) to stick with it's autoloader for any vendor-specific packages as well as your own code if it follows [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/), which it should.

```
# composer.json
{

    "require": {
        "…": "…"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "../src"
        }
    }
}

// Include composer's autoloader in your index.php.

include __DIR__ . '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Would I use this in addition to Phalcon's autoloading?

Comment: No. The only reason you'd want to deal with another autoloader if you are using external libraries but not using Composer – you don't have a choice then, unless they have their own autoloader (and a few of them do actually). Composer does a kick ass job with managing packages and autoloading, so plugging in another autoloader into the app is like adding a fifth leg to a dog.